# Is there any downside to having authentication data in a separate database from the business data?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, computer-science

Is there any downside to having all user login and administration data such as roles and permission in a database that is separate from the database that has business data? Both the databases would be on the same SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

All other things remaining same (assume you do both set ups on the same machine with the same number of cores, same memory and all other conditions same), I am hoping the difference in computing Cartesian products between data sets on two different databases will be only negligibly slower than if they were in the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very good idea. It is better to have data inside the same database and play with the `database permissions` who can access what data.

Having the data inside the same DB is better because:

1. All the data are in the same container - backups will store also this data inside.
2. Quering the same database will be better managed - from the point of view of locking.

Comment: Thank you. Thing is: frameworks such as ASP.NET Membership and now Microsoft.AspNet.Identity create a database to store authentication information. The only way for me to have a single database then would be to pollute that database with business data. I'm worried now.

Comment: Ok there is another option: if both DBs are on the same server you can add a triggers and duplicate that data inside your DB. In that case the data will be syncronized, but this will: 1) add more complexity 2) allow you to benefit only from option 2 in the answer if those frameworks will use their DB to get data.

Comment: Thank you. That is too much complexity for me. But yes, to answer 2, yes, those frameworks use their own database to query their data.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was going to. Was waiting for the time-lag to expire. Sometimes, there's a certain time before you can mark an answer right. :-)

Comment: No problem, @Water Cooler v2.

Comment: Can someone explain to me downvote? If I am correct please explain why.

Comment: I have no idea. It wasn't me, just in case you're wondering. :-)